# python select a function based on the value in a dictionary

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, dictionary

I want to select a function based on the value of a dictionary:

```
dict = {"func_selector":"func1", "param_value":"some_value"}

# defined a function
def func1(param):
  # some function code
```

Now, I want to select the function based on the value of some key, so that it can achieve something like:

```
# calling a function based on some dict value
dict["func_selector"](dict["param_value"])
```

The syntax is probably wrong, but I am wondering if it is possible to do that in Python or something similar.

Comment: Why are you not storing the function itself rather than a string? `dict = {"func_selector":func1, "param_value":"some_value"}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try storing the value of the function in the dictionary, instead of its name:

```
def func1(param):
    print "func1, param=%r" % (param,)

d = {"func_selector":func1, "param_value": "some value"}
```

Then you can say:

```
>>> d['func_selector'](d['param_value'])
func1, param='some value'
```

Comment: OP stated Python 3, `print` is missing parentheses

Answer (score 1):

The best approach IMO is do it like this

```
def func1(param):
     #code

some_value = ... #The value you need
my_dict = {"func_selector": func1, "param_value": some_value }
```

And then

```
my_dict["func_selector"](my_dict["param_value"])
```

Now, if you only have the name of the function you need to call [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#getattr)

And call it

```
getattr(my_class, my_dict["func_selector"])(my_dict["param_value"])
```

`my_class` is the class which contains the method. If it's not in a class I think you can pass `self`

Comment: `self` is not defined outside of classes, you could use `locals()` or `globals()` instead